# php simplexml_load_file() of url returns error

Tags: php, simplexml, yql

I am attempting to use Yahoos YQL language to access data via xml using
php and simplexml. I found the following code on the web:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public
/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%22sunnyvale,%20ca%22
');
```

I can paste the url in the browser and it returns the xml just fine.

When I try to access it via my php file I get the following error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity " http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%22sunnyvale,%20ca%22 " in C:\wamp\www\YQL Example\index.php on line 11

Any help would be appreciated.

Dana

Comment: What does this show? `$data = file_get_contents('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public
/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%22sunnyvale,%20ca%22); var_dump($data);`

Answer (score 1):

Your URI string is broken, the newlines in there.

Instead, assign the URI to a variable, then load it. The only "technical" reason to do so is to better organize your code because the string could be rightly placed as well inside the function call. But variables are your friend oh so often, so use them:

```
$uri = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text=%22sunnyvale,%20ca%22';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($uri);
```

Just works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="9" yahoo:created="2014-06-23T22:16:26Z" yahoo:lang="en-US"><results>

...

</results></query>
<!-- total: 40 -->
<!-- engine4.yql.bf1.yahoo.com -->
```

Answer (score 0):

`simplexml_load_file()` gets an XML file (either a file on your disk or a URL) into an object.

Use `file_get_contents()` to get the feed as a string, and use `simplexml_load_string()` then.

Comment: Internally `simplexml_load_file()` does that already. It uses the same internal mechanism like `file_get_contents()` (PHP Streams incl. the [PHP stream wrapper for HTTP](http://www.php.net//manual/en/wrappers.http.php)).